# How do I build a jeopardy game using html table and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to develop an online jeopardy game website using HTML and Javascript. I am trying to link each table cell with wager amounts to a small popup window that asks a question.

I have already created the background gameboard using an HTML table.

```
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan=5><h1>Biomedical Blazer!</h1> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td><h1> 1 </h1></td>
        <td><h1> 2 </h1></td>
        <td><h1> 3 </h1></td>
        <td><h1> 4 </h1></td>
        <td><h1> 5 </h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td id="1cat500"><h1> $500 </h1></td>
        <td id="2cat500"><h1> $500 </h1></td>
        <td id="3cat500"><h1> $500 </h1></td>
        <td id="4cat500"><h1> $500 </h1></td>
        <td id="5cat500"><h1> $500 </h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td id="1cat400"><h1> $400 </h1></td>
        <td id="2cat400"><h1> $400 </h1></td>
        <td id="3cat400"><h1> $400 </h1></td>
        <td id="4cat400"><h1> $400 </h1></td>
        <td id="5cat400"><h1> $400 </h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td id="1cat300"><h1> $300 </h1></td>
        <td id="2cat300"><h1> $300 </h1></td>
        <td id="3cat300"><h1> $300 </h1></td>
        <td id="4cat300"><h1> $300 </h1></td>
        <td id="5cat300"><h1> $300 </h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td id="1cat200"><h1> $200 </h1></td>
        <td id="2cat200"><h1> $200 </h1></td>
        <td id="3cat200"><h1> $200 </h1></td>
        <td id="4cat200"><h1> $200 </h1></td>
        <td id="5cat200"><h1> $200 </h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td id="1cat100"><h1> $100 </h1></td>
        <td id="2cat100"><h1> $100 </h1></td>
        <td id="3cat100"><h1> $100 </h1></td>
        <td id="4cat100"><h1> $100 </h1></td>
        <td id="5cat100"><h1> $100 </h1></td>
</tr>
```

I am not able to link an onClick method on Javascript with the individual cell IDs.

Comment: *"I am not able to link an onClick method on Javascript with the individual cell IDs."* How have you tried to do that? There are lots of examples of hooking up event handlers...? Show us your attempted code so we can help you understand why it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to Javascript and my attempts to link the onClick method were not successful. I will do more research as to what event handlers are. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
const cell = document.querySelector('#1cat500');

cell.addEventListener('click', e => {
   // stuff in here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Modal to pop up the window which will ask question.

Put the question in json file and utilize the fetch method of javascript which will read the json file and takes the question.